# Can not connect to AWS RDS mysql from SQLWORKBENCH

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, remote-connection, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS. I followed AWS quick start documentation and created my Web server and Database server. I can connect my Web server from my browser and ssh client. But i couldn't connect my MYSQl database from SQL workbench or MySQL yog.
I tried connecting it through command line from my web server its connecting. I thought its due to some user access problem and tried changing the user access by query and it says access denied for giving grant permissions. please suggest me the how to connect to AWS RDS from remote machine(any sql gui tool).

Comment: Please elaborate the error and error message that you get while connecting to RDS instance through workbench or MySQL yog?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's proper way, but you can create ssh tunnel like that:

`ssh -N -L 6033:RDSendpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -i /path/tokey/aws-key.pem ec2-user@EC2IPAddress`

And then connect using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port=6033 -u yorrdsuser -p` from local.

Comment: Hi, I able to connect it from command line. I can open my web server using ssh and from there i can connect my DB instance. But i want to connect from sql gui tool.

Comment: Create tunnel, keep terminal open and just connect with RDS using host 127.0.0.1 and port 6033 from your gui tool. Like that http://pl.tinypic.com/r/2mdgx6r/9